# return json object with jsonp api call

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, jsonp

I'm trying to read a json object that is returned from a JSONP API call on Angular 4, but I keep getting "undefined" in the console when I try to print it.

This is my SearchService.ts file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  apiRoot = 'this/is/my/api';
  results: any;
  loading: boolean;

  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  search(term: string) {
    const apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}&rows=10&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
    return this.jsonp.request(apiUrl).map(results => { this.results = results.json().data
    });
  }

}
```

And this is the search.component.ts file that I'm using to carry out the search:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {SearchService} from '../../services/SearchService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  loading = false;
  public result;

  constructor(private uniDirectory: SearchService) {
  }

  doSearch(term: string) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.uniDirectory.search(term).subscribe(results => this.result = results);
    this.loading = false;
    console.log('Result: ' + this.result);

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


}
```

If I try and print the result in the SearchService (i.e. `console.log(results.json());`), the json object is printed out. However, if I try to print out the same in the doSearch() method, then it prints undefined. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't quite understand how my question is a duplicate, could you provide me with a bit more guidance on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your question comes from lack of understanding of what A means in the word AJAX. Linked question has nice explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missing a return in your sevice,s `map` function,
try this one

```
search(term: string) {
const apiUrl = `${this.apiRoot}?search=${term}&rows=10&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK`;
return this.jsonp.request(apiUrl)
            .map(results => { 
                this.results = results.json().data;//you might not need this one
                return results.json(); //add this one
                });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it (someone initially posted this as an answer and removed it before I could accept it):

```
 this.uniDirectory.search(term).subscribe((results) => {
   this.result = results;
   console.log(this.result);
 });
```